# python pandas replacing strings in dataframe with numbers

Tags: python, replace, dataframe, pandas

Is there any way to use the mapping function or something better to replace values in an entire dataframe?

I only know how to perform the mapping on series.

I would like to replace the strings in the 'tesst' and 'set' column with a number
for example set = 1, test =2

Here is a example of my dataset: (Original dataset is very large)

```
ds_r
  respondent  brand engine  country  aware  aware_2  aware_3  age tesst   set
0          a  volvo      p      swe      1        0        1   23   set   set
1          b  volvo   None      swe      0        0        1   45   set   set
2          c    bmw      p       us      0        0        1   56  test  test
3          d    bmw      p       us      0        1        1   43  test  test
4          e    bmw      d  germany      1        0        1   34   set   set
5          f   audi      d  germany      1        0        1   59   set   set
6          g  volvo      d      swe      1        0        0   65  test   set
7          h   audi      d      swe      1        0        0   78  test   set
8          i  volvo      d       us      1        1        1   32   set   set
```

Final result should be

```
 ds_r
  respondent  brand engine  country  aware  aware_2  aware_3  age  tesst  set
0          a  volvo      p      swe      1        0        1   23      1    1
1          b  volvo   None      swe      0        0        1   45      1    1
2          c    bmw      p       us      0        0        1   56      2    2
3          d    bmw      p       us      0        1        1   43      2    2
4          e    bmw      d  germany      1        0        1   34      1    1
5          f   audi      d  germany      1        0        1   59      1    1
6          g  volvo      d      swe      1        0        0   65      2    1
7          h   audi      d      swe      1        0        0   78      2    1
8          i  volvo      d       us      1        1        1   32      1    1
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

What about [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)?

```
In [9]: mapping = {'set': 1, 'test': 2}

In [10]: df.replace({'set': mapping, 'tesst': mapping})
Out[10]: 
   Unnamed: 0 respondent  brand engine  country  aware  aware_2  aware_3  age  \
0           0          a  volvo      p      swe      1        0        1   23   
1           1          b  volvo   None      swe      0        0        1   45   
2           2          c    bmw      p       us      0        0        1   56   
3           3          d    bmw      p       us      0        1        1   43   
4           4          e    bmw      d  germany      1        0        1   34   
5           5          f   audi      d  germany      1        0        1   59   
6           6          g  volvo      d      swe      1        0        0   65   
7           7          h   audi      d      swe      1        0        0   78   
8           8          i  volvo      d       us      1        1        1   32   

  tesst set  
0     2   1  
1     1   2  
2     2   1  
3     1   2  
4     2   1  
5     1   2  
6     2   1  
7     1   2  
8     2   1
```

As @Jeff pointed out in the comments, in pandas versions < 0.11.1, manually tack `.convert_objects()` onto the end to properly convert tesst and set to `int64` columns, in case that matters in subsequent operations.

Comment: note that you might want to do a ``df.convert_objects()`` after the replacement to coerce to proper dtypes

Comment: @Dan Allan this will be default in 0.11.1, FYI (to convert_objects)

Comment: This is super old but you can also do this now: `df.replace(to_replace=['set', 'test'], value=[1, 2])`

Comment: I think we shouldn't ask to hardcode name of the values, It should be dynamically picked up at run time and assigned number.

Comment: For **pandas v2.2.0** this raises `FutureWarning: Downcasting behavior in 'replace' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain...`. Suggested `infer_objects(copy=False)` does not work.

Answer (score 32):

I know this is old, but adding for those searching as I was.  Create a dataframe in pandas, df in this code

```
ip_addresses = df.source_ip.unique()
ip_dict = dict(zip(ip_addresses, range(len(ip_addresses))))
```

That will give you a dictionary map of the ip addresses without having to write it out.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `applymap` DataFrame function to do this:

```
In [26]: df = DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                         "C": ['b','a','c','c','d'], "D": ['a','c',7,9,2]})
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  a  b  a
1  2  b  a  c
2  3  c  c  7
3  4  d  c  9
4  5  e  d  2

In [28]: mymap = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}

In [29]: df.applymap(lambda s: mymap.get(s) if s in mymap else s)
Out[29]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  1
1  2  2  1  3
2  3  3  3  7
3  4  4  3  9
4  5  5  4  2
```

Comment: I working on the problem like this and I just followed the exact steps mentioned in your answer. I am not getting the output.  **Code:**  wc = pd.read_csv('PATH', usecols = ['Workclass'])

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(wc) **end of line**
wcdict = {"?":0,"Federal-gov":1,"Local-gov":2,"Never-worked":3,"Private":4,"Self-emp-inc":5,
             "Self-emp-n-inc":6,"State-gov":7,"Without-pay":8} **end of line**
df.applymap(lambda s: wcdict.get(s) if s in wcdict else s) **end of line**
print(df)

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda s: mymap.get(s) if s in mymap else s)` does not make inline changes to df, so your `print df` statement will not reflect the results of the applymap. You need to do an assigment like `df2 = df.applymap(lambda s: mymap.get(s) if s in mymap else s)`. `print df2` will now reflect the changes.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks :) I have one more question, I need to work with pyspark rather than working with normal python. Does the implementation of this logic differs in pyspark? When I created a data frame, I gave the file path [as shown in above comments] but, I would like to give an RDD as the input to data frame. I couldn't do that. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Glad it worked. I'm really not sure... perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635776/can-i-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-spark-rdd) might be a start?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to replace any value in the dataframe:

```
df=df.replace(to_replace="set",value="1")
df=df.replace(to_replace="test",value="2")
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 8):

To convert Strings like 'volvo','bmw' into integers first convert it to a dataframe then pass it to pandas.get_dummies()

```
  df  = DataFrame.from_csv("myFile.csv")
  df_transform = pd.get_dummies( df )
  print( df_transform )
```

***Better alternative***: passing a dictionary to map() of a pandas series (df.myCol)
(by specifying the column brand for example)

```
df.brand = df.brand.map( {'volvo':0 , 'bmw':1, 'audi':2} )
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pandas.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html#pandas.factorize) does exactly this.

```py
>>> codes, uniques = pd.factorize(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> codes
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0]...)
>>> uniques
array(['b', 'a', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

With a DataFrame:

```py
df["tesst"], tesst_key = pandas.factorize(df["tesst"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with pandas `rename_categories`. You would first need to define the column as `dtype="category"` e.g.

```
In [66]: s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")

In [67]: s
Out[67]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

and then rename them:

```
In [70]: s.cat.rename_categories([1,2,3])
Out[70]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

You can also pass a dict-like object to map the renaming, e.g.:

```
In [72]: s.cat.rename_categories({1: 'x', 2: 'y', 3: 'z'})
```

Comment: in general, what is this category type for?

Comment: @HerrIvan there's plenty of documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Answer (score 2):

When no of features are not much :

```
mymap = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5}
df.applymap(lambda s: mymap.get(s) if s in mymap else s)
```

When it's not possible manually :

```
temp_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': data.data.unique(), 'data_new':range(len(data.data.unique()))})# create a temporary dataframe 
data = data.merge(temp_df2, on='data', how='left')# Now merge it by assigning different values to different strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build `dictionary` from `column` values itself and fill like below

```
x=df['Item_Type'].value_counts()
item_type_mapping={}
item_list=x.index
for i in range(0,len(item_list)):
    item_type_mapping[item_list[i]]=i

df['Item_Type']=df['Item_Type'].map(lambda x:item_type_mapping[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.replace(to_replace=['set', 'test'], value=[1, 2])` from @Ishnark comment on accepted answer.