# Map string values in a Pandas Dataframe with integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas `DataFrame` how to map strings in one column with integers. I have around 500 strings in the `DataFrame` and need to replace them with integers starting with '1'.

Sample `DataFrame`.

```
                                    Request  count
547             GET /online/WebResource.axd  37506
424              GET /online/2/2/22001.aspx  13315
699          POST /online/2/6/1/261001.aspx  13236
546          GET /online/ScriptResource.axd  12255
492               GET /online/2/6/Home.aspx  10462
660             POST /online/2/2/22001.aspx   9803
```

I have taken all the Requests in to a list.

```
requestlist = df.Request.unique()
```

No idea of how to map these Requests with 1-500. Similar question. [python pandas replacing strings in dataframe with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114904/python-pandas-replacing-strings-in-datarame-with-numbers)

Comment: So you want to parse the url request to search for the string before the .axd or .aspx and then convert to an int? What will you do with this int, will this form an index or does it map to another column?

Comment: @EdChum : There is no association with the url and the integer we are mapping. I just need to map them in order to make it more easy for other processing.

Comment: So you just want to enumerate the unique requests is that correct?

Comment: @EdChum : 'GET /online/WebResource.axd' is identified by 1, 'GET /online/2/2/22001.aspx' identified by 2 etc?

Comment: What will you do with this enumeration? will this form a new column or dataframe or you just want a dict to perform the lookup?

Comment: @EdChum : I want to have these values in a separate column in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So what you could do is construct a temporary dataframe and merge this back to your existing dataframe:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Request': df.Request.unique(), 'Request_id':range(len(df.Request.unique()))})
```

Now merge this back to your original dataframe

```
df = df.merge(temp_df, on='Request', how='left')
```