# Is there a memory efficient way to replace a list of values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, memory-management, replace, large-data

I am trying to replace all of the unique strings in a large pandas dataframe (1.5 million rows, and about 15 columns) with an integer index.  My problem is that my dataframe is 2Gigs and my list of unique strings ends up with around eighty thousand or more entries.

To produce my list of unique strings I use:

```
unique_string_list = pd.unique(df.values.ravel()).tolist()
```

Then if I try to use df.replace() either with a pair of lists or with a dictionary the memory overhead is too much for my 8 Gigs of RAM.  The problem is in the size of the replacement list so even if I only use a few thousand row chunk of the dataframe it will eat all the RAM:

```
mapdict = dict(zip(unique_string_list, range(len(unique_string_list))))
replacedict = dict(zip(df.columns.values, [mapdict for column in df.columns.values]))
df.replace(replacedict)
```

I have tried looping over the string list instead.  This reduced the memory overhead but it is very inefficient and takes too long to run (longer than overnight).

Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `df.map(replacedict)`? Or you could create a series using the unique strings as the index and the integer values as the values and again call map pass this series

Comment: Another option is to use sklearn's [DictVectoriser](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the DictVectoriser will add some serious memory overhead to this dataframe, so I am not sure that would be the best way to do it.  I will try to use the applymap method tonight, but I am sceptical that it would be any better than replace.

Comment: I think your best bet is to just create a Series with the unique string values as the index, then just assign an increasing int value for the series and then use this as the param to the `map` call: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346552/map-string-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-integers/22346955#22346955 this uses merge but you could just call map if this was a Series

Comment: I made something that works, but there is probably a better way to do this.  For each column in my dataframe `df[column] = df[column].map(mapdict)`.  `apply` doesn't seem to work on a dataframe.  Thank you!