# Returning unique values in .csv and unique strings in python+pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

my question is very similar to here: [Find unique values in a Pandas dataframe, irrespective of row or column location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084382/unique-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

I am very new to coding, so I apologize for the cringing in advance.

I have a .csv file which I open as a pandas dataframe, and would like to be able to return unique values across the entire dataframe, as well as all unique strings.

I have tried:

```
for row in df:
    pd.unique(df.values.ravel())
```

This fails to iterate through rows.

The following code prints what I want:

```
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row, object):
            print('%s\n%s' % (index, row))
```

However, trying to place these values into a previously defined set (myset = set()) fails when I hit a blank column (NoneType error):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row, object):
        myset.update(print('%s\n%s' % (index, row)))
```

I get closest to what I was when I try the following:

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row, object):
            myset.update('%s\n%s' % (index, row))
```

However, my set prints out a list of characters rather than the strings/floats/values that appear on my screen when I print above.

Someone please help point out where I fail miserably at this task. Thanks!

Comment: The reason the first line: `for row in df:` fails is because this returns the columns rather than the rows

Comment: Yes, thanks, but when I try:
    'code'for index, row in df.iterrows():
         pd.unique(df.values.ravel())'code'
I get a first row that repeats (apparently infinitely) without ever seeming to progress to printing values of additional rows indices.

Comment: What you are doing in that case is trying to get a flattened unique set of values for the whole df. What are you ultimately trying to achieve, for instance you can get an array of all the unique values by doing `pd.unique(df.values)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me the following error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.unique(df.values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 54, in unique
    values = com._asarray_tuplesafe(values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 1491, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = values
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (36634,18) into shape (36634)"

However, your suggestion is very similar to one here in my next comment below (space issues)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492270/is-there-a-memory-efficient-way-to-replace-a-list-of-values-in-a-pandas-datafram

`unique_string_list = pd.unique(df.values.ravel()).tolist()`
Upon entering `unique_string_list` after this line, I appear to get a list of unique values, but I think I am running out of memory shortly after this.

What I want is a list of all unique values in the dataframe, and generally all unique strings to pare this to a manageable size. My ultimate use for these values is look at correlations among subgroupings of data and flag groupings of interest. Ran out of spac

Comment: I'm not sure you will be able to get the data in that way, you could create a dict of the unique values for each col like so :`vals={} for col in df: vals[col] = df[col].unique()` would give you a dict of all the unique values for each column

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for almost any dataframe. It will extract each value that is unique in the entire dataframe.

Post a comment if you encounter a problem, i'll try to solve it.

```
# Replace all nones / nas by spaces - so they won't bother us later
df = df.fillna('')

# Preparing a list
list_sets = []

# Iterates all columns (much faster than rows)
for col in df.columns:
    # List containing all the unique values of this column
    this_set = list(set(df[col].values))  
    # Creating a combined list
    list_sets = list_sets + this_set

# Doing a set of the combined list
final_set = list(set(list_sets))

# For completion's sake, you can remove the space introduced by the fillna step
final_set.remove('')
```

#### Edit :

I think i know what happens. You must have some float columns, and fillna is failing on those, as the code i gave you was replacing missing values with an empty string. Try those :

1. df = df.fillna(np.nan) *or*
2. df = df.fillna(0)

For the first point, you'll need to import numpy first (`import numpy as np`). It must already be installed as you have pandas.

Comment: This looks really good, but I am having a slight problem with the first line (and probably the last).
I get "ValueError: could not convert string to float."

Comment: Try the update after the edit. The problem is due to your dataframe having some floats.

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more specific... yes, I have floats in my dataframe. I was also able to filter out my returned values as strings, if desired, with the optional code following.
    `unique_value_list = pd.unique(df.values.ravel()).tolist()

    remove = []
    for i in unique_value_list:
     if isinstance(i, (int, float)):
      remove.append(i)
     unique_string_list = list(set(unique_value_list) - set(remove))`