# How to plot lines based on the existence of continuous data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset that looks like the below:

```
+------------+--------+
| trend_name |  date  |
+------------+--------+
| dogs       | 5/3/17 |
| cats       | 5/3/17 |
| owls       | 5/3/17 |
| dogs       | 5/4/17 |
| cats       | 5/4/17 |
| tigers     | 5/4/17 |
| cats       | 5/5/17 |
| bears      | 5/5/17 |
| giraffes   | 5/5/17 |
+------------+--------+
```

I'd like to create a plot that has `trend_name` on the y-axis and `date` on the x-axis with lines connecting trends that continue for >1 periods and the same plane of the trend and a dot for trends that only exist for a single period and nothing if a trend does not exist for a particular period.

The plot would look something like this:
[image]

I tried simply `t.plot(x='date', y='trend_name')` but of course there is no data, so it threw an error.

Is there a specific name for this type of plot so I can find better resources or does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

t is a pandas dataframe like this, but follows a similar pattern to he mock dataframe above:

[image]

`t.plot(x='datetime_collected', y='name')` yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-d2a37de17ec0> in <module>()
----> 1 t.plot(x='datetime_collected', y='name')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   3772                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   3773                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 3774                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   3775     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   3776 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2641                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2642                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 2643                  **kwds)
   2644 
   2645 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   2468         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   2469 
-> 2470     plot_obj.generate()
   2471     plot_obj.draw()
   2472     return plot_obj.result

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in generate(self)
   1039     def generate(self):
   1040         self._args_adjust()
-> 1041         self._compute_plot_data()
   1042         self._setup_subplots()
   1043         self._make_plot()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.pyc in _compute_plot_data(self)
   1148         if is_empty:
   1149             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
-> 1150                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
   1151 
   1152         self.data = numeric_data

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: That is a standard plot. As you mention, you need your data. Where is it stored? What is `t` in your code? Which library are you using?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo This is in a standard pandas dataframe.  I guess i could create a column with booleans or maybe 1s and 0s?  From there i'm not sure what to do though

Comment: @ImanolLuengo i guess there is no "data".  I'd just like to plot based on the existence of a `trend_name`,

Comment: You shouldn',t need to create a boolean array, two columns of the datafram should do the job. Can you put the whole traceback of your error? You might want to look for scattet plot (to plot the raw values), then work something else for lines.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo updated the question with the requested info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that this is far from the most elegant solution, especially since I'm not very familiar with pandas. But anyway, here's a solution which creates an auxiliary dataframe for your plot limits (this is inevitable if you want to ignore data points which are not represented in your current time window):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# dummy data
dat = pd.DataFrame({'beast': ['dog','cat','owl','dog','cat','tiger','cat','bear','giraffe','unicorn'],
                    'collected': pd.to_datetime(['2016-03-09']*3 + ['2016-04-05']*3 + ['2016-05-05']*3 + ['2016-06-06'])})

# plotting date interval
t1,t2 = (pd.to_datetime(t) for t in ('2016-03-09','2016-05-05'))

# create auxiliary dataframe for plotting
dat_tmp = dat[(t1<=dat.collected) & (dat.collected<=t2)] # filtered between t1 and t2
beast_id,beasts = zip(*enumerate(dat_tmp.beast.unique()))

# indexing step: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22346955
dat_tmp = dat_tmp.merge(pd.DataFrame({'beast': beasts, 'beast_id': beast_id}),on='beast',how='left')
dat_tmp = dat_tmp.pivot(index='collected',columns='beast',values='beast_id')

# plot
dat_tmp.plot(style='.-')

def format_fn(tick_val, tick_pos):
    '''uses items in the list `beasts` to set yticklabels'''
    if int(tick_val) in beast_id:
        return beasts[int(tick_val)]
    else:
        return ''

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_fn))
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

As you can see, there's still a lot of room for formatting improvements: hiding irrelevant x ticks, zooming out a bit to fully show all the points, moving around the legend, etc., but those are trivial facelifts.

As for the dummy example I put together (I suggest you do the same yourself next time, makes it easier for others to play around with your problem), we started out with this dataframe:

```
     beast  collected
0      dog 2016-03-09
1      cat 2016-03-09
2      owl 2016-03-09
3      dog 2016-04-05
4      cat 2016-04-05
5    tiger 2016-04-05
6      cat 2016-05-05
7     bear 2016-05-05
8  giraffe 2016-05-05
9  unicorn 2016-06-06
```

Note the unicorn data point which is altogether missing from the plot. After the indexing/merging step we end up with

```
     beast  collected  beast_id
0      dog 2016-03-09         0
1      cat 2016-03-09         1
2      owl 2016-03-09         2
3      dog 2016-04-05         0
4      cat 2016-04-05         1
5    tiger 2016-04-05         3
6      cat 2016-05-05         1
7     bear 2016-05-05         4
8  giraffe 2016-05-05         5
```

As you can see, each point has been annotated with the integer index of the given animal. We need this, as this is the data we need for the `y` axis of our plot. After pivoting the final result is

```
beast       bear  cat  dog  giraffe  owl  tiger
collected                                      
2016-03-09   NaN  1.0  0.0      NaN  2.0    NaN
2016-04-05   NaN  1.0  0.0      NaN  NaN    3.0
2016-05-05   4.0  1.0  NaN      5.0  NaN    NaN
```

the columns of which will be plotted as separate lines. There's likely a shorter course of action that results in the same or equivalently useful data frame, but this is all I've got. The upside is that the `NaN`s in the data set will automagically enforce your "lines where data are contiguously available" rule.