# Can I convert pandas dataframe to spark rdd?

Tags: pyspark

Pbm:

a) Read a local file into Panda dataframe say PD_DF
b) Manipulate/Massge the PD_DF and add columns to dataframe
c) Need to write PD_DF to HDFS using spark.  How do I do it ?

Comment: Why don't you read the local file into a Spark dataframe directly?

Comment: As I said, I want to use pandas DF to manipulate the data before writing it into HDFS using spark.  Not sure if spark dataframe supports all the features that is support by pandas dataframe

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `SQLContext` object to invoke the `createDataFrame` method, which takes an input `data` which can optionally be a Pandas `DataFrame` object.

Comment: I am aware of that option.  But trying to see if there is a direct way to convert a DF to RDD without creating a schemaRDD.

Comment: `schemaRDD` has been replaced by DataFrames in Spark 1.3. Call `df.rdd.map(lambda x: [e for e in x])` if you don't want your RDDs elements to be `Row` instances. Although I don't really see why you'd want that. What format do you want to save to?

Comment: Plan is to read a csv file from NFS and after manipulation using panda df, swap it to spark rdd and write it as avro/parquet file in hdfs.  Also, do spark DF support all the features currently supported by pandas DF?

Comment: From documentaton at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame When schema is None, it will try to infer the schema (column names and types) from data, which should be an RDD of Row, or namedtuple, or dict.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say `dataframe` is of type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame then in spark 2.1 - Pyspark I did this

```
rdd_data = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe)\
                .rdd
```

In case, if you want to rename any columns or select only few columns, you do them before use of `.rdd`

Hope it works for you also.

Answer (score 3):

I use Spark 1.6.0. First transform pandas dataframe into spark dataframe then spark dataframe spark rdd

```
sparkDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandasDF)
sparkRDD = sparkDF.rdd.map(list)
type(sparkRDD)
pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
```