# replace strings in every column with numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114904/python-pandas-replacing-strings-in-dataframe-with-numbers). Consider the pandas DataFrame visualized in the table below.

|  | respondent | brand | engine | country | aware | aware_2 | aware_3 | age | tesst | set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | volvo | p | swe | 1 | 0 | 1 | 23 | set | set |
| 1 | b | volvo | None | swe | 0 | 0 | 1 | 45 | set | set |
| 2 | c | bmw | p | us | 0 | 0 | 1 | 56 | test | test |
| 3 | d | bmw | p | us | 0 | 1 | 1 | 43 | test | test |
| 4 | e | bmw | d | germany | 1 | 0 | 1 | 34 | set | set |
| 5 | f | audi | d | germany | 1 | 0 | 1 | 59 | set | set |
| 6 | g | volvo | d | swe | 1 | 0 | 0 | 65 | test | set |
| 7 | h | audi | d | swe | 1 | 0 | 0 | 78 | test | set |
| 8 | i | volvo | d | us | 1 | 1 | 1 | 32 | set | set |

To convert a column with String entries, one should do a map and then `pandas.replace()`.

For example:

```
mapping = {'set': 1, 'test': 2}
df.replace({'set': mapping, 'tesst': mapping})
```

This would lead to the following DataFrame (table):

|  | respondent | brand | engine | country | aware | aware_2 | aware_3 | age | tesst | set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | volvo | p | swe | 1 | 0 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | b | volvo | None | swe | 0 | 0 | 1 | 45 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | c | bmw | p | us | 0 | 0 | 1 | 56 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | d | bmw | p | us | 0 | 1 | 1 | 43 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | e | bmw | d | germany | 1 | 0 | 1 | 34 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | f | audi | d | germany | 1 | 0 | 1 | 59 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | g | volvo | d | swe | 1 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | h | audi | d | swe | 1 | 0 | 0 | 78 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | i | volvo | d | us | 1 | 1 | 1 | 32 | 1 | 1 |

As seen above, the last two column's strings are replaced with numbers representing these strings.

**The question is then:** Is there a faster and not so hands-on approach to replace all the strings into a number? Can one automatically create a mapping (and output it somewhere for human reference)?

Something that makes the DataFrame end up like:

|  | respondent | brand | engine | country | aware | aware_2 | aware_3 | age | tesst | set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 45 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 56 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 43 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 34 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 59 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 65 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 78 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 32 | 1 | 1 |

Also output:

```
[{'volvo': 1, 'bmw': 2, 'audi': 3}, {'p': 1, 'None': 2, 'd': 3}, {'swe': 1, 'us': 2, 'germany': 3}]
```

Note that the output list of maps (dicts) should not be hard-coded but instead produced by the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the other answers, I've written this function to do solve the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def convertStringColumnsToNum(data):
    columns = data.columns
    columns_dtypes = data.dtypes
    maps = []
    
    for col_idx in range(0, len(columns)):
        # don't change columns already comprising of numbers
        if(columns_dtypes[col_idx] == 'int64'): # can be extended to more dtypes
            continue
        # inspired from Shivam Roy's answer 
        col = columns[col_idx]
        tmp = pd.Categorical(data[col])
        data[col] = tmp.codes
        maps.append(tmp.categories)

    return maps
```

This function returns the `maps`s used to replace strings with a numeral code. The code is the index in which a string resides inside the list. This function works, yet it comes with the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

*if it ain't broke don't fix it, right? ;)*

*but if anyone has a way to adapt this function so that the warning is no longer shown, feel free to comment on it. Yet it works *shrugs* *

Answer (score 0):

You can adapte the code given in this response
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989896/15320403 (inside the post you linked) to generate a mapping for each column of your choice and apply replace as you suggested

```
all_brands = df.brand.unique()
brand_dic = dict(zip(all_brands, range(len(all_brands))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first change the type of the columns to `Categorical` and then create a new column or overwrite the existing column with `codes`:

```
df['brand'] = pd.Categorical(df['brand'])
df['brand_codes'] = df['brand'].cat.codes
```

If you need the mapping:

```
dict(enumerate(df['brand'].cat.categories )) #This will work only after you've converted the column to categorical
```