# Pandas: Large CSV file data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I have a large dataset from a CSV file. It has two columns, the first is Date/Time in hh:mm:ss:ms form and the other is Pressure in number form. The pressure has randon values throughout that are not numerical values (things like 150+AA42BB43). These appear randomly throughout the 50,000 rows in the file and are not the same.

I need a way to change these Pressure values to numeric so I can perform data manipulation on them.

```
df_cleaned = df['Pressure'].loc[~df['Pressure'].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, float) | isinstance(x, int))]
```

I tried this, but it got rid of my Date/Time values and also did not clean all the pressure values  while also getting rid of my headers.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how I can easily clean the data in the 2nd column while also keeping my Date/Time values in the first column accurate.

Comment: you should rather use `df_cleaned = df.loc[....] ` (or even `df_cleaned = df[....]`) instead of `df['Pressure'].loc[...]`

Comment: Using `df_cleaned = df['Pressure']...` you get only one column (`Pressure`) and you skip other columns - and this is why you don't have `Date/Time`. And because it is single column so it may give it as `Series` instead of `DataFrame` - and this can remove your header(s) because Series (single column) doesn't need header.

Comment: you can do `isinstance(x, (float, int))`

Comment: How exactly do you want to clean the pressure values? Just get rid of the non-numeric characters and convert to a float?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you use

```
df_cleaned = df['Pressure']
```

and this get only one column (`Pressure`) and skip other columns. And when you get single column then it may gives you `Series` instead of `DataFrame` - and `Series` can keep only one column so it doesn't need `header` to select columns.

You should run it without `['Pressure']`

```
df_cleaned = df.loc[ ~df['Pressure'].map(...) ]
```

or even

```
df_cleaned = df[ ~df['Pressure'].map(...) ]
```

---

**BTW:** shorter `isinstance(x, (float, int))`

But using `isinstance` may not work if you have `float/int` values as strings - because `isinstance("123", (float, int))` gives `False` - and you would have to rather try to convert `float("123")` and `int("123")` and catch error.

---

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'DateTime': ['2021.10.04', '2021.10.05', '2021.10.06'], 
    'Pressure': [78, '150+AA42BB43', 23], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_cleaned = df[ df['Pressure'].map(lambda x:isinstance(x, (float, int))) ]

print(df_cleaned)
```

Result:

```
     DateTime Pressure
0  2021.10.04       78
2  2021.10.06       23
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have values as string then you can use `to_numeric` to convert them and put `NaN` if value can't be converted

```
df['Pressure'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pressure'], errors='coerce')
```

and then you can filter it usinf `isna()`

```
df_cleaned = df[ ~df['Pressure'].isna() ]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'DateTime': ['2021.10.04', '2021.10.05', '2021.10.06'], 
    'Pressure': ['78.2', '150+AA42BB43', '23'], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Pressure'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pressure'], errors='coerce')
print(df)

df_cleaned = df[ ~df['Pressure'].isna() ]
print(df_cleaned)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've an answer if all your non-numerical values are strings.

Have you tried using pandas replace()? Something like:

```
df['Pressure'].replace(to_replace = r'.+', value=0, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

I've used a regex to determine "any string". `inplace=True` allows that the existing dataframe is modified, instead of creating a new one.

Here, the function will replace any string with a given integer. I am not sure which integer you'd like to put there, so I've just used zero as an example. If you'd like a different integer for each string, you could use a map as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17115229/13621247).