# Pandas replace() string with int "Cannot set non-string value in StringArray"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm trying to replace strings with integers in a pandas dataframe. I've already visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114904/python-pandas-replacing-strings-in-dataframe-with-numbers) but the solution doesn't work.

Reprex:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.__version__

> '1.4.1'


test = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [None, 'Y', 'N', '']}, dtype = 'string')
test.replace(to_replace = 'Y', value = 1)

> ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '1' into a StringArray.
```

I know that I could do this individually for each column, either explicitly or using `apply`, but I am trying to avoid that. I'd ideally replace all `'Y'` in the dataframe with `int(1)`, all `'N'` with `int(0)` and all `''` with `None` or `pd.NA`, so the `replace` function appears to be the fastest/clearest way to do this.

Comment: You can change the column from `string` type to `object` type which will allow you to set mixed datatypes in that column

Comment: The issue is that not all columns in my actual data are needing conversion. I have over 300 columns, but only some subset has Y/N/'' values. Would your approach require converting all columns to `object`? Or, would I have to explicitly hardcode which columns to convert to `object'? Ideally I'd convert only columns that need converting, without hardcoding.

Comment: It's a highly pragmatic over performant solution, but is there a reason you need to have your other columns be single-typed? Could you just convert the entire DF to object? Otherwise, if you're staying single-typed, would '1' work  as well as 1 for whatever operations you need to do next?

Comment: Or just the string columns: `for i in test.select_dtypes('string').columns: test[i] = test[i].astype(object)`

Comment: Yeah you're right, I ended up just converting the whole thing to `object`, then using the `pandas.convert_dtypes()` function to back-convert, and it pretty much takes care of everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int8Dtype`. `IntXXDtype` allow integer values and `<NA>`:

```
test['b'] = test['a'].replace({'Y': '1', 'N': '0', '': pd.NA}).astype(pd.Int8Dtype())
print(test)

# Output
      a     b
0  <NA>  <NA>
1     Y     1
2     N     0
3        <NA>
```

```
>>> [type(x) for x in test['b']]
[pandas._libs.missing.NAType,
 numpy.int8,
 numpy.int8,
 pandas._libs.missing.NAType]
```